# std::thread in template class

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I have a problem and can't seem to figure out what's wrong here. 
I try to create a number of threads in a static member function of a template class. Here the code snippets that causes the problems:

```
  for(unsigned long rIndex=0; rIndex<pRLength; rIndex+=1){
    for(unsigned long sIndex=0; sIndex<pSLength; sIndex+=1){
      for(unsigned long tIndex=0; tIndex<pTLength; tIndex+=1){
        threads[threadIndex] = std::thread(
          JMatrix<T>::blockByBlockShallow,
          lhs, rhs,
          r, (r+=partitionR[rIndex])-1,
          s, (s+=partitionS[sIndex])-1,
          t, (t+=partitionT[tIndex])-1,
          fanInMatrices[sIndex]
        );
        threadIndex+=1;
        rIndex+=1;
        sIndex+=1;
        tIndex+=1;
      }
    }
  }
```

blockByBlockShallow is a private static member function of the `JMatrix` template class. 
Here the compiler output:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I./inc -c -o bin/.JMatrix src/jmatrix.cpp -lpthread
In file included from ./inc/jmatrix.hpp:11:0,
                 from src/jmatrix.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7.1.1/thread: In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(JMatrix<char>&, JMatrix<char>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char>&), JMatrix<char>, JMatrix<char>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char> > >':
/usr/include/c++/7.1.1/thread:127:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(JMatrix<char>&, JMatrix<char>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char>&); _Args = {JMatrix<char>&, JMatrix<char>&, long unsigned int&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int&, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char>&}]'
src/jmatrix.cpp:266:32:   required from 'static JMatrix<T> JMatrix<T>::multiplyFanIn(JMatrix<T>&, JMatrix<T>&, long unsigned int*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int*, long unsigned int, long unsigned int*, long unsigned int) [with T = char]'
src/jmatrix.cpp:347:16:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.1.1/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(JMatrix<char>&, JMatrix<char>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char>&), JMatrix<char>, JMatrix<char>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char> > >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(JMatrix<char>&, JMatrix<char>&, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char>&), JMatrix<char>, JMatrix<char>, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, long unsigned int, JMatrix<char> > >::_Indices)'
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
```

Any suggestions? I've tried a couple of things and I am quite lost here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `JMatrix<T>::blockByBlockShallow` a static member function of the *class-template* `JMatrix`?  Just out of curiosity... Do you really need that number of threads?? ..

Comment: And how are we expected to know what is the declaration of your static function and if it is visible? Also, `&` in front of the member functions (to take a pointer to it) is mandatory.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the blockByBlockShallow function

Comment: Whoa - tripple nested for loops - I hope those containers are small or the combined runtime will go through the roof.. (also `rIndex+=1` is something I don't see too often - not wrong as such, but why not `++rIndex`? (prefix increment should generally be prefered if you can use it (potentially faster for user-defined types) and "++" is also somewhat shorter and more conventional).

Comment: Please post complete minimal example that we can paste to compiler.

Comment: Start by simplifying. Get rid of those loops; they have nothing to do with the problem (although they have a couple of problems that you'll have to deal with later). Try to create a **single thread**. Get that working, then add the complications back in.